# Dynamic DLL with call back procedure - Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll

I want to load a DLL function dynamically. 
This function runs good on static DLL mode. But I can not manage it to work on dynamic mode.

```
type
  TCallBackProcedure = procedure(StringValue: PAnsiChar;
    IntegerValue: integer)stdcall;

type
  TOpenPort = function(dnum: integer;
    CallBackString: TCallBackProcedure): integer;


function xOpenPort(dnum: integer; CallBackString: TCallBackProcedure): integer;

const

  tDLL = 'myDll.dll';

function OpenPort(dnum: integer; CallBackString: TCallBackProcedure): integer;
  stdcall; external tDLL;

procedure CallBackString(StringValue: PAnsiChar; integerValue : Integer) stdcall;
begin
  strAA := StringValue; // string
  SLb.Add(strAA); // StringList
end;
```

run in static mode has no problem.

```
 iOutput := OpenPort(9, @CallBackString); // working fine
```

This is my effort to call it in dynamic load ;

```
function xOpenPort(dnum: integer; CallBackString: TCallBackProcedure): integer;
var
  hDll: THandle;
  xOpen: TOpenPort;
begin
  try
    hDll := loadLibrary(tDLL);
    if hDll <> 0 then
    begin
    //load dll OK 
      @xOpen := getProcAddress(hDll, 'OpenPort');
      if @xOpen <> nil then
      begin
        Result := 5;
      // I see also function is loaded
        Result := xOpen(dnum, @CallBackString);  
        prn(IntToStr(Result));
      end;
    end;
  finally
    freeLibrary(hDll);
  end;
end;
```

How I call :

```
iOutput := xOpenPort(9, @CallBackString);  // access violation
```

I got access violation. How to call any DLL like this in dynamic load  ? I have many function like this in static mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition of the `TOpenPort` type is missing the `stdcall` calling convention, like your static definition of `OpenPort()` is using:

```pascal
type
  TOpenPort = function(dnum: integer; CallBackString: TCallBackProcedure): integer; stdcall;
```

Without that calling convention, Delphi's default `register` calling convention is used instead, causing the parameter values to be passed via CPU registers instead of on the call stack, where the DLL function expects to find them.

Also, in your `xOpenPort()` function, do not use the `@` operator when passing the `CallBackString` parameter to `xOpen`. The parameter is already the correct type. You need to pass its value (ie the memory address of a callback function), not the memory address of the parameter itself, so just pass it as-is to `xOpen`:

```pascal
Result := xOpen(dnum, CallBackString);
```

Comment: Is it correct the way I call is like this `iOutput := xOpenPort(9, @CallBackString);  I still have access violation`

Comment: @Bianca again, you need to get rid of the `@` operator, it doesn't belong in this code: `iOutput := xOpenPort(9, CallBackString);`

Comment: well, i laugh loudly to my self. hahhahaha. Thank you , Sir! All done. I now understand. Very appreciate this.